# I am not sure, but it's an equation...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, exponentiation

$$2x + 2^x = 4$$
So it's clear that $x$ will equal $1$ but how can it be solved through an algebraic method to be able to determine $x$ with more complex numbers.

I've tried to transform the exponent into a logarithm 
 
$ 2x + \log_2 2^x = 4$ 
$2x +x = 4$ 
$x = \frac43$ 
But it didn't work...

Comment: There is no 'simple' algebraic method to solve this equation and what you have written is incorrect. Solving this equation is however related to the $W$-Lambert function, if you are looking for a closed form solution in terms of a well studied function.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $x=1$ is solution. Moreover, if $f(x)=2x+2^x$,$$f'(x)=2+\ln(2)2^x>0$$ and thus, $f$ is injective. Therefore, $x=1$ is the unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the function
$$
f(x)=2x+2^x
$$
you see that
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty
$$
and
$$
f'(x)=2+2^x\log 2>0
$$
for every $x$. Thus the function is strictly increasing and so it takes exactly once every possible real value.

Since, clearly,
$$
f(1)=2\cdot1+2^1=4
$$
you see that the only solution of your equation is $x=1$.

There is no simple “algebraic” solution. What you can say is that, for every real $a$, there is a unique $x$ such that $2x+2^x=a$. Such $x$ can be determined with the desired accuracy with some approximation method.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Nice, but it's not “algebraic” as you claim, because it uses the same tool as I used, the fact that a function is increasing. Since both $x\mapsto 2x$ and $x\mapsto 2^x$ are increasing, it's obvious that $x\mapsto 2x+2^x$ is increasing too.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Sorry, I fully disagree: what about $2x+2^x=5$? You're implicitly using that the solution is $x=1$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas When you show me how you solve the problem with $5$, I'll answer back. Not earlier.